# EF Core - Ignore Query Filters for an entity type, but keep filter for JOINs

Tags: entity-framework-core

In my project I have a soft-delete flag (DateDeleted) for every entity.
In some occasions, I want to know, which entities got deleted.

The soft-delete is implemented as a query filter in Fluent API.

```cs
entity.HasQueryFilter(e => !EF.Property<DateTime?>(e, "DateDeleted").HasValue);
```

When I want to include the deleted entities, I am using `IgnoreQueryFilters()` in my LINQ statement.

```cs
DbContext
    .MyEntries
    .IgnoreQueryFilters();
```

My issue is, that it not only returns deleted items of the type I'm querying, but also deleted items in included/JOINed entities.

Normally it would look something like this:

```json
[
  {
    id: 1,
    relations: [{
      id: 1,
      DateDeleted: null
    },{
      id: 2,
      DateDeleted: null
    }],
    DateDeleted: null
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    relations: [{
      id: 4,
      DateDeleted: null
    },{
      id: 5,
      DateDeleted: null
    }],
    DateDeleted: null
  }
]
```

`IgnoreQueryFilters()` returns something like this:

```json
[
  {
    id: 1,
    relations: [{
      id: 1,
      DateDeleted: null
    },{
      id: 2,
      DateDeleted: null
    },{
      id: 3,
      DateDeleted: "2022-12-31T23:59:59.999Z" //I don't want this Entry.
    }],
    DateDeleted: null
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    relations: [{
      id: 4,
      DateDeleted: null
    },{
      id: 5,
      DateDeleted: null
    }],
    DateDeleted: null
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    relations: [{
      id: 6,
      DateDeleted: "2022-12-31T23:59:59.999Z" //I don't care if I get those or not.
    },{
      id: 7,
      DateDeleted: "2022-12-31T23:59:59.999Z" //I don't care if I get those or not.
    }],
    DateDeleted: "2022-12-31T23:59:59.999Z"
  }
]
```

Currently I need to filter those unwanted sub-entities explicitly.

Is there a way to ignore query filters only on the top level?

Comment: `IgnoreQueryFilters` ignores all filters and there is no way to change this behavior.  From other side you can use filtered `Include` - `query.IgnoreQueryFilters().Include(q => q.relations.Where(r => r.DateDeleted == null))`

Comment: Thats a bummer. Are there any thid-party extensions that have this ability?